# Running Ansible task throws shared connection closed error

Tags: xpath, ansible

I have written a task for ansible-xml module.

```
- name: Learning xml module
  xml:
    file: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/sme/WEB-INF/sme-servlet.xml
    xpath: //ref/[@abcd="test"]
```

I am getting the following Error :

```
failed: [xxxx] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
BECOME-SUCCESS-ezlukfdsowbhzcovltxcovwmgbziywxu
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Shared connection to xxxx closed.
```

Comment: What's in ssh_config?

Comment: Host *
    KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com ....

Comment: It was too long i will share the value for attribute you want to check

Comment: Look for controlmaster, which version of ansible are you using and can you ssh to the box correctly?

Comment: Nothing like control master. Ansible version is 1.9.3. Yeah i can ssh and it works for other playbooks written.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ansible adds some options which override `ssh_config` options. Specifically, it adds:

```
-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/user/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r"
```

Figured that out by using `-vvv` with `ansible-playbook`.

## How to fix:

You can override those options by specifying `ssh_args` in the `[ssh_connection]` section of your `.ansible.cfg` as specified [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args). Changing `ssh_args` doesn't actually change all of the args because Ansible also passes `-C -tt -v -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o ConnectTimeout=10` and other options (e.g. `-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root`), some of which are simply immutable defaults, and some of which depend on variables you've specified in the playbook.